# Вызов определенного segue + передача данных на новый ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uicollectionview

В сториборд от одного и того же контроллера (в иерархии `NavigationController`) создал две разных `segue` и пытаюсь по клику определить какой из них вызвать + передаю данные в вызываемый контроллер. Переход осуществляется корректно, а данные не передаются...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В `CollectionView` в методе `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` пишу:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

// Если нажал на ФОТО
if (indexPath.row > numvideos - 1)
{
    // Если при этом в галерее присутствует ВИДЕО
    if (numvideos != 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Нажал на фото с индексом: %d", indexPath.row + 1 - numvideos);

        PhotoFullScreenViewController *photoFullScreenViewController = [[PhotoFullScreenViewController alloc] init];
        photoFullScreenViewController.numberOfSelectedPhoto = indexPath.row + 1 - numvideos;
        photoFullScreenViewController.numberOfTotalPhotos = galleryArray.count - numvideos;

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToPhotoFullScreen" sender:nil];
    }
    // Если ВИДЕО в галерее не присутствует
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Нажал на фото с индексом: %d", indexPath.row + 1);

        PhotoFullScreenViewController *photoFullScreenViewController = [PhotoFullScreenViewController new];
        photoFullScreenViewController.numberOfSelectedPhoto = indexPath.row + 1;
        photoFullScreenViewController.numberOfTotalPhotos = galleryArray.count;

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToPhotoFullScreen" sender:nil];
    }

}
// Если нажал на ВИДЕО
else
{
    NSLog(@"Нажал на видео с номером: %d", indexPath.row + 1);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToVideoFullScreen" sender:nil];
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно либо 
1. конфигурить `UIViewController` в

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goToPhotoFullScreen"]) {
        PhotoFullScreenViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController; // получаем экземпляр из segue
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForSelectedItem]; // получаем выбранный NSIndexPath
        if (indexPath) {
           /* configure your UIViewController with selected indexPath */
        } 
    }
}
```

При этом в `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToPhotoFullScreen" sender:nil];
}
```

либо можно настроить в сториборде чтобы при выборе ячейки всегда осуществлялся переход (segue)

2. еще один вариант - убрать segue, назначить вашему `UIViewController` storyboard id, это делается в сториборде, на вкладке с классом, чуть ниже, допустим "PhotoFullScreen", дальше в `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` в нужный момент просто делаем

   PhotoFullScreenViewController *vc = [self.storybard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"PhotoFullScreen"];
   /* configure it here */
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated: true];

а то, что вы делаете - вы создаете новый `PhotoFullScreenViewController` без использования сториборда, конфигурите его, а дальше просите сториборд создать его и осуществить переход. То есть ваш код конфигурации в итоге ничего не делает и `UIViewController` создается неправильно, не так, как вам нужно

Comment: Спасибо, воспользовался первым вариантом. Смысл я понял - всегда я пытаюсь вызвать переход через segue [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToPhotoFullScreen" sender:nil]; - будет вызываться и - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goToPhotoFullScreen"]) {... в котором мне и надо передать данные. Верно?

Comment: @Chekist prepareForSegue будет вызван всегда, даже если вы настроили переход прямо в сториборде от кнопки или ячейки. Если вы хотите дальше отловить переход в prepareForSegue обязательно дайте ему identifier. Главное, что вы поняли принцип. Кстати, второй вариант ничем не хуже первого, разве что менее нагляден в сториборде, но использовать его зачастую удобнее